# Are there guidelines for DiagnosticId for custom analysis?

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

With the possibility to write custom code analysis, I wonder if there are any guidelines for identifier of a diagnostic.

The documentation of [DiagnosticDescriptor](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/a4e375b95953e471660e9686a46893c97db70b0e/src/Compilers/Core/Portable/Diagnostic/DiagnosticDescriptor.cs#L67) only mentions that it should be unique, but are there other guidelines for example on how the prefix them?